# How to pass a object though function-created-button

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function add_text(text){
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += text;
}//add text to output.
function reset(){
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";
}

function show_button(){
var obj = {a:"item"}
add_text('<button onclick="myFunction(' + "'" +obj+ "'" + ')">button</button>');
}//a button created by function.

function myFunction(x){
reset();
//here x is {a:"item"}, wouldn't x["a"] give {a:"item"}["a"] i.e. "item" in output?
add_text(x["a"]);
}
show_button();
//however after click the button, output shows "undefined" instead of "item".
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

In this code, the show_button function created a button in div as output, when click the button, it active myFunction and pass though a object obj={a:"item"} as a parameter, but I'm not sure why it interpret obj["a"] as "undefined" instead of "item", how do I fix this?

Comment: You should use `.textContent` instead of `.innerHTML`.

Comment: Also, your script is vulnerable to various injection attacks.

Comment: can you help us understand why you need to call the function with obj as parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute your `show_button` with this:

```js
function show_button(){
  var obj = {a:"item"}
  var output = document.getElementById("output") // get target element
  var button = document.createElement('button')  // create the button
  button.innerText = 'button' // change the text
  button.addEventListener('click', () => myFunction(obj)); // attach the click handler
  output.appendChild(button); // append the button to the target element
}
```